# Measure without measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question, definitions, alternative-proof

This question is a little on the softer and speculative side, so bear with me.

Usually a measurable space is $(\Omega, \Sigma)$, a set $\Omega$ and sigma algebra $\Sigma$ of subsets. A measurable function $f:\Omega \to \Omega'$ is one such that for every $A\in \Sigma '$ we have that $f^{-1}(A)\in \Sigma$.

Let $\Omega'$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual Borel measure. We say that a (let's say probability) measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ acts on a measurable $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ by $$\mu (f) \equiv \int\limits_{\Omega} f(x) \, d\mu (x) .$$

This is a way to define measures, in many settings — by the way they act on measurable functions.

**My question:** is there a way to define measures solely through classes (I guess algebras? not sure) of functions? Something like: given a class of functions $\mathcal{F}$ from $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, a measure is a functional on $\mathcal{F}$ with such and such properties.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what's done in (one of) the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem)?

Comment: @LSpice I don't see it straight away, since it says something about which measures are dual to very particular classes of functions, no?

Comment: The Riesz representation theorem tells you that _every_ positive linear functional on continuous compactly supported functions on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ comes from a Radon measure on $X$, and vice versa. So it would seem you can't do better than "positive linear functional" for some classes of $\mathcal{F}$!

Comment: This is actually really common in the literature (though maybe not in elementary textbooks). See: Daniell integral. If you e.g. read the opening parts of Federer's Geometric Measure Theory, he discusses such approaches at length.

Comment: Amir, not sure if this is what you are searching for, but perhaps this book (the very last one) by Constantin Carathéodory, *Algebraic theory of measure and integration.* 2nd ed. (English) New York: Chelsea pp. 378 (1986), [MR0917481](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0917481), [Zbl 0665.28001](https://zbmath.org/0665.28001) is what you need.

Comment: (**Continued from the previous comment**...) Carathéodory builds measure and integration theory entirely from the concept of *soma* (*σώματα*), thought as an element of a boolean algebra. From this he builds the concept of measure, then the concept of point function and allied integral: this approach has been somewhat popular within the scholars working on continuum physics (thermomechanics + electrodynamics) since the soma formalizes quite effectively the concept of physical body.

Comment: Actually this was also somehow the approach of Bourbaki, that is measures mainly on topological spaces as linear functionals on spaces of continuous functions.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, that is the approach of Daniell and Stone. To see how the approach works and how general it is, you can take a look at the four-part series on "Notes on Integration" by M. H. Stone. See [here](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.34.7.336), [here](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.34.9.447), [here](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.34.10.483), and [here](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.35.1.50).

Comment: This are fantastic,  thank you. Do you know if this broader sense of integration was ever used (i.e., in cases where it cannot be reduced to "usual" measure and integration)?